# How to deleted More than One record from a Particular SQlite Table in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a table like below:

```
ID    Name    Phone   Address
-----------------------------
1     xyz       980      abc
2     sdf       382      sdff
3     hdj       322      abc
4     jks       346      abc
5     sdfd      344      abc
```

I want to delete all records which is having `Address = "abc"` and `Phone = {"980", "346", "322"}`

How can I fulfill the above query in Android SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should it be enough?

```
db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE column_address='abc'
AND column_phone IN ('980', '346', '322')");
```

in case you want to do it via delete method, then i assume you may do it by:

```
    for(String phone : phoneNumbers){
        db.delete("my_table", "column_address = ? AND column_phone = ?",
        new String[]{"abc", phone});
    }
```

Comment: Hi Waqas, thanks for the respose. I mean the right one. I am trying to the second one without for loop. column_phone values come different always and in larger number (not just only 3 value as I mentioned).

Comment: I dont know if you can achievve this without using for loop. But in case, you want to delete large number of records and i can suggest you to use for-loop and sqlite transaction to achieve this. It will be fast enough to not to notice any considerable delay. Whenever you need to insert,update or delete huge number of records together, then always use transactions. They make things fast.

Comment: Query should be `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE column_address='abc'
AND column_phone IN ('980', '346', '322')`. Delete * does not work.

Answer (score 1):

this will help you

```
delete from Table where Address = 'abc' and (Phone = '980' or Phone = '980' or Phone = '322')
```

Comment: `Phone = '980' or Phone = '980'`? And `IN` operator can be used here.